# Why do bokeh tutorials use explicit imports rather than aliases?

Tags: python, bokeh

As I was checking out the Bokeh package I noticed that the tutorials use explicit import statements like `from bokeh.plotting import figure` and `from numpy import linspace`. I usually try to avoid these in favor of, e.g., `import numpy as np`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I thought this is considered good practice as it helps to avoid namespace contamination.

Is there any reason why Bokeh deviates from this practice, and/or are there common aliases to use for Bokeh imports (e.g. `import bokeh.plotting as bp`)?

Comment: Either way is fine - the "namespace" is about what you want to put in it, and explicitly using an import to put something in the namespace is a choice. The main thing to avoid is `*` imports as they can create confusion about what is actually being imported.

Comment: Plotting in bokeh uses many different sub-modules that don't all exist in `bokeh.plotting`.  For instance, `bokeh.models`, `bokeh.layouts`, `bokeh.models.widgets`, etc.  Instead of coming up with a new abbreviation for everything, they typically just import the functions they need out of them.

Comment: @tmwilson26 That makes sense. Perhaps this is a bit far-fetched, but would there be a way to 'bundle' all my bokeh imports under a common alias?

Comment: One way you could do it is to put all of your import statements into a separate file, importing the functions you want to have available (or * if you want to risk it).  You can then import that file into your main file with an alias.  Something like `import my_bokeh_funcs as bpt`.  Any function that is available in that file will be made available to you main program under the `bpt` alias.

Comment: @tmwilson26 Great suggestion. If you combine your comments in an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `bokeh` has many different sub-modules from which you can pull functions for your plot that are outside of `bokeh.plotting`, there is not one all encompassing package that you can import to access all of the functions.  One way to get around this is to create your own sub-package in a separate file which will import all of the functions that you want to have access to in your main file.  For instance, you could create a file name `my_bokeh.py` in the same directory as your main script, and put in the following imports (for example):

```
from bokeh.models import Range1d,ResizeTool,HoverTool,ColorBar,LinearColorMapper,BasicTicker,Title,BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import row,widgetbox
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
```

Now, in your main script, you can import this sub-package as:

```
import my_bokeh as bpt
...
bpt.figure(x_range=bpt.Range1d(0,x-1,bounds='auto'),
           y_range=bpt.Range1d(0,y-1,bounds='auto'),
           plot_width=200, plot_height=200)
...
p.add_tools(bpt.ResizeTool())
...
bpt.show(p)
```

You'll have access to each function under the `bpt` alias as seen in the script above and you can keep the import statements in your main script clean.

Answer (score 0):

Importing individual names from a library isn't really "contamination".  What you want to avoid is doing `from somelibrary import *`.  This is different because you don't know which names will be imported, so you can't be sure there won't be a name clash.

In contrast, doing `from numpy import linspace` just creates one name `linspace`.  It's no different from doing creating an ordinary variable like `linspace = 2` or defining your own function with `def linspace`.  There's no danger of unexpected name clashes because you know exactly which names you're creating in your local namespace.

Comment: I see your point, but it does deviate from common tutorials for matplotlib or numpy, for example. I generally like the commonly-used aliases as it is immediately clear (also to others reading your code) to which module the `figure` belongs. Going back to my question, I'd like to know whether there is a specific reason *not* to use aliases, and whether there are standard aliases for bokeh if you *do* want to use them.

Comment: @Peter9192: It just depends on what you want to do.  "Common tutorials" for matplotlib or numpy often use many functions from the libraries, not just one or two, so it makes sense to import the module rather than doing `from numpy import <20 functions I need>`.  If the code you're looking at really does only use one or two numpy functions, then it makes sense to just import those.  In many cases it's just a matter of personal preference.  As for whether there's a standard abbreviation for bokeh, that I don't know.